# Knn search for large data?

Tags: algorithm, search, machine-learning, knn

I'm interested in performing knn search on large dataset.

There are some libs: [ANN](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~mount/ANN/) and [FLANN](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~mariusm/index.php/FLANN/FLANN), but I'm interested in the question: how to organize the search if you have a database that does not fit entirely into memory(RAM)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose it depends on how much bigger your index is in comparison to the memory. Here are my first spontaneous ideas:

1. Supposing it was tens of times the size of the RAM, I would try to cluster my data using, for instance, hierarchical clustering trees (implemented in FLANN). I would modify the implementation of the trees so that they keep the branches in memory and save the leaves (the clusters) on the disk. Therefore, the appropriate cluster would have to be loaded each time. You could then try to optimize this in different ways.
2. If it was not that bigger (let's say twice the size of the RAM), I would separate the dataset in two parts and create one index for each. I would therefore need to find the nearest neighbor in each dataset and then choose between them.

Comment: You are right, we need to use some hierarchical representation, but maybe there is some ready to use solution?

Comment: Maybe there is, but I haven't heard of any. Moreover, I believe that this really is a problem of optimizations that are specific to your situation (e.g. is it more costly to make more computations in order to access the disk less times, or is it cheap to access the disk in comparison to your computation power?). Let us know if you find something...

Comment: `I would try to cluster my data using, for instance, hierarchical clustering trees`. Is a  `kdd` or `ball` tree such a method?

Answer (score 4):

It depends if your data is very high-dimensional or not. If it is relatively low-dimensional, you can use an existing on-disk [R-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) implementation, such as [Spatialite](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/).

If it is a higher dimensional data, you can use [X-Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-tree), but I don't know of any on-disk implementations off the top of my head.

Alternatively, you can implement [locality sensitive hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing) with on disk persistence, for example using mmap.

Comment: Why it depends on dimension size?

Comment: It's about the so called curse of dimensionality (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality): in higher dimensional spaces, the data becomes very sparse and all your data points start looking equally (dis)similar. So for example methods using similarity measures such as euclidean distance stop working well.

Comment: I have vector size about 24*32 or 32*32 is it big or small? What metric should I use instead of euclidean distance?